# What do you think about wishing a merry christmas on meta

Tags: discussion

Because there are several users not visiting the chat do you think it would be nice to wish "merry christmas" on German (normaly off-topic, I know) or on meta? Or have the moderators a possibility to include a message on the german SE side?

BTW: Merry Christmas ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I love to see seasonal greetings we should keep in mind that these are valid for a very short time only.

In addition as seasonal greetings are not really questions we could answer in a sensible way they would be off topic in any case.

The appropriate place to wish our community members a Merry Christmas or a Happy New Year is the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). By starring a message there we can also make it more prominent.

Comment: On TeX SE you can see for example a message "Visit the ongoing interview of xyz" when an interview is running or "Visit answering the unanswered questions (starting in one hour)". I had such a message in mind. I think moderators can switch it on/off.

Comment: The use of the system-message banners for general announcements and non-critical events was discouraged. For announcements or Meta posts of general interest we may use the Community Bulletin board.

Comment: I didn't know that and had never read something like that in the faq.